# React hooks synchronise two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a function that gives me an array of strings who depends if checkboxes are checked or not.

I want to fill another array with hooks method like so

`const [firstArray, setFirstArray] = useState([]);
...
const myFunction = (array) => {
    // array like so => [firstString, secondString, etc..]
    array.forEach(arr => {
        setFirstArray([...firstArray, ...arr])
        // if function array change i want to filter firstArray
        if(??){
            setFirstArray(
                firstArray.filter(check => check !== arr)
            )
        }
    }
    
}`

which way is the best ?

Comment: What you are doing is pretty confusing to me. I would suggest you to look at this Checkboxes example: https://codesandbox.io/s/string-checkboxes-koz56?file=/src/App.js and read the React documentation regarding form inputs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply @maxpsz, the problem is that i use antdesign library and for CheckboxGroup present here https://ant.design/components/checkbox/, onChange function return an array not just "e.target.value"

Comment: I don't think so, look at this example from its documentation: https://codesandbox.io/s/09ov3

Comment: Yes this is a simple checkbox here, my problem occurs when using a checkbox group

Comment: Then it's even more easy, i will post an answer, ask if you don't understand something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just should update your state whenever the onChange function is triggered:

```
const App = () => {
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);

  const onChange = (checkedValues) => {
    setSelectedOptions(checkedValues);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Checkbox.Group
        options={options}
        defaultValue={selectedOptions}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```